# Google smart home mode traits are not displaying in ui

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I am trying to display the custom modes in my google home app. But the mode are not displaying.

Below are the traits which are used in the sync intent.

```
{
  "response": {
    "requestId": "3824625397483970421",
    "payload": {
      "agentUserId": "be855ca8-7be8-4e4c",
      "devices": [
        {
          "id": "device--92ada020-074a-11ed",
          "type": [
            "action.devices.types.VACUUM"
          ],
          "traits": [
            "action.devices.traits.StartStop",
            "action.devices.traits.Modes"
          ],
          "name": {
            "defaultNames": [
              "Vacuum Cleaner 2"
            ],
            "name": "Vacuum Cleaner 2",
            "nicknames": [
              "Vacuum Cleaner 2"
            ]
          },
          "willReportState": true,
          "roomHint": "",
          "structureHint": "",
          "attributes": {
            "availableModes": [
              {
                "name": "suction",
                "name_values": [
                  {
                    "name_synonym": [
                      "suction"
                    ],
                    "lang": "en"
                  }
                ],
                "settings": [
                  {
                    "setting_name": "Storm",
                    "setting_values": [
                      {
                        "setting_synonym": [
                          "Storm"
                        ],
                        "lang": "en"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "setting_name": "Gust",
                    "setting_values": [
                      {
                        "setting_synonym": [
                          "Gust"
                        ],
                        "lang": "en"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "setting_name": "Breeze",
                    "setting_values": [
                      {
                        "setting_synonym": [
                          "Breeze"
                        ],
                        "lang": "en"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "setting_name": "Eco",
                    "setting_values": [
                      {
                        "setting_synonym": [
                          "Eco"
                        ],
                        "lang": "en"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "ordered": false
              }
            ]
          },
          "otherDeviceIds": [
            
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong. I read the documentation but looks fine to me but still it not displaying in the google home app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our teams are constantly working to improve Google Home App and the controls available in the UI. Right now for certain traits the touch controls are not available in the UI. For these controls you can always initiate them through voice.

Your Sync response looks right for Vacuum . If you need touch controls for modes on a vacuum device on Google Home App, you can create a feature request in [Public Issue Tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/). This will help us with the prioritization in our roadmap.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

What I have observed is there is a difference in terms of touch controls modes that are not available in google smart home app but can be controlled via the voice commands. Modes can only be displayed for now in the nest display.

Reference
https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/touch-controls